# How can I test code with History records?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, history-tracking

I've recently developed a small visualforce component that displays any object's child's `__History` records.

I have to make tests with the `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` because I can't retrieve the historical records in the own test execution context (I imagine because they have not yet been inserted?).

Well, the problem I have encountered is that when deploying to a Production environment sometimes the tests don't pass because the data that my queries bring isn't consistent. But, I can't actually make them consistent because the field `Field` can't be used as a filter with `LIKE` operand and `NewValue` and `OldValue` can't be used as filters either.

Is there any way to make my tests more consistent when working with `_History` records?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought would be to try using [Test.loadData()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm), but I haven't tried that yet myself. Difficulty in testing is a big part of the reason why I ended up choosing to make my own "history" object when working on a project a few years ago.

Comment: Aside from the duplicate you could refactored your code to during tests return a history record deserialized from a constructed json object